# Python - accessing files from C drive in Azure notebook

Tags: python, azure

I have h5 file in C drive. I cannot upload the dataset in h5 in Azure as it is in 468 MB. How can I read it from the code itself. Without Azure, having the jupyter notebook on local machine, I can access using following coede :

with h5py.File('SVHN_single_grey1.h5','r') as hdf:

This doesn't work in Azure as it cannot access local files on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your H5 file accessed directly from internet via an url, you can try to use the code as below to read it in Azure Notebook.

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import h5py

r = requests.get("<an url for accessing your H5 file, such as https://host:port/.../SVHN_single_grey1.h5>")
f = BytesIO(r.content)
with h5py.File(f) as hdf:
    ...
```

If not, you have to publish the H5 file as a resource url to an internet service first, then to use it via the code above. I recommended to use the Azure offical tool [`azcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy) to help uploading it as a blob to Azure Blob Storage, please refer to the offical tutorial [`Tutorial: Migrate on-premises data to cloud storage by using AzCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-migrate-on-premises-data?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=windows) to know more details. Then, you can follow the sample code below to read it again.

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import h5py

account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'
blob_name = '<your blob name>'

blob_service = BaseBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)

sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
# print(sas_token)
url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)
# print(url_with_sas)

r = requests.get(url_with_sas)
f = BytesIO(r.content)
with h5py.File(f) as hdf:
    ...
```

Alternatively, here is the other sample code that also works fine.

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
from io import BytesIO
import h5py

account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'
blob_name = '<your blob name>'

blob_service = BaseBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)

stream = BytesIO()
blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name, blob_name, stream)
with h5py.File(stream) as hdf:
    ...
```